# How to see which file is being used to define a serializaiton behavior?

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I am debugging an existing Symfony 2.8 application.

It uses JMS serializer to serialize some information related to an image. Now I want to add another existing field to the list of fields that get serialized.

The problem is that there are two XML files that define serialization behaviors (and maybe some yml or annotations that I don't know about), and I'm not sure where the behaviors are defined.

**Is there a debugging method I can call to find out where serialization behaviors are being defined?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the yml file that was influencing our exposure behavior by just looking in the same folder where my XML files (called `Entity.Media.xml` and `Model.Media.xml`) lived.

That was where I found the relevant file, which was called `Model.Media.yml`.

I'm still hoping there's a more elegant way to debug this stuff, so I'm leaving the question open.